# Setup Windows Remote Desktop on port 80?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have a VM on Internet. I have a port limitation on my windows. 
Is it possible to setup Windows Remote Desktop on port 80?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article describes how to change the port that Remote Desktop listens on. Note The Remote Desktop Connection Client for the Mac supports only port 3389. 3389 is the default port.

1. Start Registry Editor
2. Locate and then click the following registry sub-key:

[image]

3. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\

[image]

4. RDP-Tcp\PortNumber

[image]

5. On the Edit menu, click Modify, and then click Decimal.

[image]

6. Type the new port number, and then click OK.

[image]

7. Quit Registry Editor.
8. Please follow this steps carefully or you will have trouble connecting via RDP.

Source [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Listening-Port-for-Remote-Desktop)

Comment: Somebody can tell me the reason why I get the down vote for my answer???

Comment: Probably because your answer isn't an answer... it's a link only.  Link-only answers are discouraged here, and are better left up to a comment.

Comment: ..and you have used a non-privileged port (1800) as an example.